# How to use google performance visualization tool to visualize a custom data

Tags: debugging, google-visualization, timeline

Assume a multicore processor running different parts of code, I need to plot them in a visual way to analyze how much time is taken by each section of code in corresponding cores and see how they are line up.
I have this data in a custom format. I need to visualize it for debug and analysis.

Google performance timeline visualization as shown below is a perfect match for such a use case.
[image]

But as far as I know it can show only website performance data. Is it possible to use it to view a custom data other than a website performance info.

Google timeline chart is not having as versatile features as in Google performance timeline.
Is there any alternate that can fit such a need.

[Edit]

Below are the items which I am not able to figure out

1. Its showing everything on a date / time basis with millisecond granularity, my need was to show it on a microsecond granularity without any date. preferably starting from 0 micro second
2. When cursor hover on top of a item, I need to show the time taken by that item in microseconds.

[image]

Is there any feature in Google timeline chart which I am missing?

Below is my html code which I generated from my custom data

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Timeline | Custom styling</title>

    <style>
      body, html {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11pt;
      }

      #visualization {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
      }

      .ggl-tooltip {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 8px;
      }

      .ggl-tooltip span {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      
      .vis-item.openwheel  { background-color: #B0E2FF; }
      .vis-item.rally      { background-color: #EAEAEA; }
      .vis-item.motorcycle { background-color: #FA8072; }
      .vis-item.touringcar { background-color: #B4EEB4; }
      .vis-item.endurance  { background-color: #FFFFCC; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <div id="example5.1"></div>
    <script src="vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js"></script>
    <link href="vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--    -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
      The style of the Timeline can be fully customized via CSS:
    </p>
    <div id="visualization"></div>

    <script>
      // https://motocal.com/
      var groups = new vis.DataSet([
      {"content": "CPU1", "id": "CPU1", "value": 1, className:'openwheel'},
      {"content": "CPU2", "id": "CPU2", "value": 2, className:'rally'}
      ]);

      // function to make all groups visible again
      function showAllGroups(){
        groups.forEach(function(group){
          groups.update({id: group.id, visible: true});
        })
      };

      // note that months are zero-based in the JavaScript Date object
      var items = new vis.DataSet([
        {start: 1, end: 3, group:"CPU1", content:"fft"},
        {start: 6, end: 9, group:"CPU2", content:"sqrt"},
        {start: 1, group:"CPU1", content: '<div>alloc</div><img src="up.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">'},
        {start: 2, group:"CPU1", content: '<div>freeMem</div><img src="down.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">'},
        {start: 3, group:"CPU1", content: '<div>response</div><img src="response.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">'},
        {start: 6, group:"CPU2", content: '<div>alloc</div><img src="up.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">'},
        {start: 7, group:"CPU2", content: '<div>freemem</div><img src="down.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">'},
        {start: 9, group:"CPU2", content: '<div>response</div><img src="response.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">'}
      ]);

      var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
      var options = {
        groupOrder: function (a, b) {
          return a.value - b.value;
        },
        groupOrderSwap: function (a, b, groups) {
          var v = a.value;
          a.value = b.value;
          b.value = v;
        },
        groupTemplate: function(group){
          var container = document.createElement('div');
          var label = document.createElement('span');
          label.innerHTML = group.content + ' ';
          container.insertAdjacentElement('afterBegin',label);
          var hide = document.createElement('button');
          hide.innerHTML = 'hide';
          hide.style.fontSize = 'small';
          hide.addEventListener('click',function(){
            groups.update({id: group.id, visible: false});
          });
          container.insertAdjacentElement('beforeEnd',hide);
          return container;
        },
        editable: true,
        margin: {
          item: 20,
          axis: 40
        }
      };

      // var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
      var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container);
      timeline.setOptions(options);
      timeline.setGroups(groups);
      timeline.setItems(items);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you add your current results using google timeline chart and explain what google timeline chart does not have AND you need? - I made a quick search and [highcharts gantt](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gantt) looks promising, but, again, without the specifics, it's very hard to  give an definitive answer...

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Please find the edited section in the question

Comment: Thank you for add the code, but, please, add the correct references (i.e. where `<script src="vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js"></script>` comes from?) - consider use https://jsfiddle.net/ or the [code-snippet here in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/12511801) for create a [mcve] - like [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mattg8000/xfm2dc8z/).

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I got that js file from a git repo. But as you suggested I tried out highcharts gannt, it looks really good and I made a sample out of it. I have added the same code in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ogtjzdwx/1/) . Please guide me on a) How can I make this to not to map it to a date, I am looking for something that starts from 0 microsecond onwards. b) How can I make it to zoom in and out with mouse scroll wheel. c) How to add custom string when mouse hover over an item.

Comment: Is it possible to add markers in the timeline such as allocate memory, free memory, response recieved, etc

Comment: a) For format the value as microseconds, check [this entry on Hightcharts forums](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7535). b) about zooming, read in the [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/zooming) and this [entry in their fourms](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=45045) - I can't help further, but with this info you can complete the requirement. Good luck.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Thank you so much, I will be able to go through and get it done by going through the suggested docs. 

Is highcharts a paid software, from its website it looks like that. Is it free to use the demo files?